# Print 2^64 integer in c++

Tags: c++, biginteger

I was solving a programming problem in c++. And the problem said that **The input numbers are not greater than 2^64.**

How can I work with that big number in c++? I have to use subtraction with the number also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`uint64_t` / `unsigned long long` can store numbers from 0 to 2^64-1, so if you either don't have input of exactly 2^64, or special case handling for it (for example, by setting a boolean and using an alternative formula when necessary), you may get away with using `uint64_t`.  This will be even less promising if the values may be negative, as the magnitude of numbers int64_t can handle will be -2^63...2^63-1....

You could use [`long`] `double` or `float` to store the numbers - for some larger integers the values may be approximations.

You could also get a library able to handle very large numbers - e.g. "GMP" - google it if interested.

Answer (score 2):

There is a data type: The `long long` which is guaranteed to have at least 64 bits (as of C++11). Assuming you don't have negative values, you can store values up to 2^64 (but not including) in a variable of type `unsigned long long`.